# Missing Payment Plugin Extension In Opencart

Tags: ftp, installation, opencart, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I currently finished writing a payment plugin for opencart. I uploaded it using filezilla to an online opencart site, tested it and it worked perfectly.
After which i tried installing the same plugin using the extensions installer from admin, setup my ftp and i got a "installed successfully" message.

The problem is i can't find the extension under payment extensions in the opencart site. As in, it is completely missing but it definitely has to be somewhere since it installed successfully

NOTE

1. The previously installed plugin through filezilla cannot be possibly crashing with the new one because i removed that one completely.
2. I setup my FTP perfectly.
3. I zipped the upload folder, saved it with upload.ocmod.zip before uploading it.

How do i find the missing extension and if i'm installing it the wrong way, what is right way to go about the it.

Comment: To be honest I didn't use ftp feature provided by Opencart because of server limitation and more requirements. So what I exactly do in this case: 
I wrote extension, put some instruction in ocmod-file. But I never using zip-ocmod. Many modules has packet in it's own archive and write some readme-files. Anyway if you're going to use zip-ocmod files - find some working example and see what's going on

Comment: Possible it can be wrong file structure in zip

Comment: My files are supposed to update specific folders in admin and catalog. i place this files in the respective path within the folders, then i put the admin and catalog folder inside an upload folder and zipped it @AlexSlipknot

Comment: so in fact your archive does not include those files?

Comment: No, they don't..i'm kinda bothered because when i uploaded the plugin using filezilla, it worked perfectly. i found all the files in the respective folders i wanted them to be

Comment: Then you should try to install / enable it in extensions tab. It should be there

Comment: It's not there. I actually removed the one i uploaded with filezilla to test it with the extensions installer and it showed that the upload was successful but i can't find it among payments in extensions

Comment: or maybe there is a particular way of uploading extensions in opencart using the extensions installer, i don't know

Comment: Can you post some code example to anyone can check what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCart 2.3, all extensions are listed in the Extensions > Extensions area. You then have to choose which extensions you want to filter on (e.g. Shipping extensions).

Which Opencart version you are using?

Comment: I'm using version  2.3.0.2